# Key of BibTeX entry to appear in BBL file

Tags: bibtex, bst

I'm using the cv BST by Christian Plessl and would like the BibTeX entry key to appear in the `\cvitem` command in the BBL file. For example, out of the entry:

```
@proceedings{yh19graf,
    Editor = {Haralambous Yannis},
    Publisher = {Fluxus Editions},
    Title = {Graphemics in the 21st Century 2018. Proceedings},
    Year = {2019}}
```

I would like to obtain not

```
\cvitem{\cvdurationstyle{2019}}
{Haralambous Yannis, editor.
\newblock {\em Graphemics in the 21st Century 2018. Proceedings}. Fluxus
  Editions, 2019.
}
```

but

```
\cvitem{\cvdurationstyle{2019}}%yh19graf
{Haralambous Yannis, editor.
\newblock {\em Graphemics in the 21st Century 2018. Proceedings}. Fluxus
  Editions, 2019.
}
```

The code for producing the `\cvitem` entry is as follows:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\cvitem{\cvdurationstyle{" write$
  year year.or.none write$
  "}}" write$
  newline$
  "{" write$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

I tried to modify it by adding a `"%" write$ key write$`:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\cvitem{\cvdurationstyle{" write$
  year year.or.none write$
  "}}" write$
  "%" write$
  key write$
  newline$
  "{" write$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

the `%` appeared but not the key. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
cite$ write$
```

instead of `key write$`. From [TameTheBeast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), p. 33

> `cite$` puts on the stack the internal key of the current entry

or [`btxhak`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf), p. 6

> `cite$` Pushes the string that was the `\cite`-command argument for this entry.

As far as I know the *entry key* of the bibliography entry is usually not available as a regular field in the BibTeX language, you need to use the built-in `cite$`. `key` is really the field `key` in the `.bib` file (that can be used as a fallback if `author` and `editor` are missing).

Comment: Thank you so much for that accurate and fast answer!